# TikZ arrows pointing only to the superscript exponent

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
\begin{frame}


\frametitle{Nazewnictwo}

\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\large

\[
\tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t1){\Huge{$a$}};}
 \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=red!20,anchor=base ] (t2){\Huge{$^n$}};}
\]

  \begin{itemize}
 \item[]<2-> \tikz\node [fill=blue!50,draw,circle] (n1) {}; podstawa
  \item[]<3-> \tikz\node [fill=red!50,draw,circle] (n2) {}; wykładnik
   \end{itemize}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
     \path<4->[blue,->] (n1.north) edge [out= 60, in= 135] (t1.north west);
    \path<5>[red,->] (n2.south) edge [out=-70, in=-110] (t2.south);

       \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

And that's what I would like to have:

[image]

Is there any way in which I can make the arrow point directly to the exponent and the highlighted red rectangle adequately smaller as in the 2nd picture?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to make the node written as a superscript to make it look like it. The math font size command `\scriptstyle` is actually does it for you together with `\displaystyle,\scriptscriptstyle` etc.

Also you can put the item disks as an argument to `\item` macro. Lastly, you need to remember those pictures.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,lmodern}
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex,remember picture]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Nazewnictwo}

\large

\[
\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{
\node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t1){\Huge{$a$}};
\node[fill=red!20,anchor=west] at (t1.north east) (t2){\Huge{$\scriptstyle n$}};
}
\]

  \begin{itemize}
 \item[{\tikz[na]{\node [fill=blue!50,draw,circle] (n1) {};}}]<2->  podstawa
 \item[{\tikz[na]{\node [fill=red!50,draw,circle ] (n2) {};}}]<3->  wykładnik
   \end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \path<4->[blue,->] (n1.north) edge [out= 60, in= 135] (t1.north west);
    \path<5>[red,->] (n2.south) edge [out=-70, in=-110] (t2.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats what I was going to say too :-)

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Tobi Ah, I hate when that happens. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. Wasn’t so much work in this case :-)